# PHP count not working

Tags: php, count

Mysql shows my record count as 50000 
but when I check `count($results);` It shows my result as empty.

This is weird, cos when I traverse the result set I'm looping through 50000 records as well.

So I'm thinking:

- 1) Am I going over the maximum amount of records count() can handle?
- 2) is there another function I can use instead of count ?

Below is my code:

```
<?php


$query   = "SELECT
   *,
   pl.user_id 
FROM
   passengers_log as pl 
   join
      tabel2 as t2 
      ON t2.id = t1.id 
   Join
      tabel3 as t3 
      ON t3.id = t2.id 
   Join
      tabel4 as t4 
      ON t4.id = t3.id 
   Join
      tabel5 as t5 
      ON t5.id = t4.id 
   Join
      tabel6 as t6 
      ON t6.id = t5.id 
   Join
      tabel7 as t7 
      ON t7.id = t6.id 
WHERE
   pl.status = '1' 
   and pl.reply = 'A' 
   and pl.createdate >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' 
   and pl.createdate <= '2016-11-23 14:19:41' 
order by
   pl.passengers_log_id desc";
$results = Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query)->execute()->as_array();

print_r($results);//returns 50000
count($results);//it returns empty results 
?>
```

PS: I get 50000 records when I executed the query. In php it returns 50000 array results, so this is working fine. But in php `count($result);` gives me nothing, instead of 50000 it shows an empty result.

Comment: We can't tell without seeing the code. Usually, both mysql and count are reliable.

Comment: 1) the maximum size of `count` is the maximum size of a number on your system, which you will never reach because any array even remotely that size would overfill your RAM. 2) no, and why should there? 3) what **exactly** is your question about? it's hard to understand what your problem is. please take a look at **[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Show your code. The error might be in your query.

Comment: hi Olaf thanks for your reply,actually my problem is in my database i have 50000 records when  i executed the query it returns 50000  array results this one is working fine. for example i have array(0=>....to 50000=>) but in php i am check  count($result);means instead of 50000 it was shows empty result.

Comment: sry for my poor english

Comment: Show us the code! We are talking about nothing here and you can't get an answer without showing anything

Comment: $query="SELECT *,pl.user_id FROM `passengers_log` as pl 
join `tabel2` as t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
Join `tabel3` as t3 ON t3.id=t2.id
Join `tabel4` as t4 ON t4.id=t3.id
Join `tabel5` as t5 ON t5.id=t4.id 
Join `tabel6` as t6 ON t6.id=t5.id 
Join `tabel7` as t7 ON t7.id=t6.id  
WHERE pl.status = '1' and pl.reply = 'A' and pl.createdate >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' and pl.createdate <= '2016-11-23 14:19:41' 
order by pl.passengers_log_id desc"
$results = Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query)
->execute()
->as_array();

Comment: //print_r($results);while print i got 50000 results 
return count($results);//it returns empty results

Comment: above is my code also my application we used kohanaframe

Comment: My guess would be that ->as_array() does not actually return an array, but an iterator. Do `print_r(Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query) ->execute() ->as_array())` and see if the first line of output indicates an actual array, or an object.

Comment: @Yuvaraj edit your question and add that code on it

Comment: @Yuvaraj **don't** post code in comments. **edit** your original question instead!

Answer (score 0):

Kohana DB query result offers a `count` method. Try this:

`$result = Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query)->execute();
print 'Number of results is: '.$result->count();`

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing any mistake for writing query to get the result from database, otherwise count always gives the number of rows which are returning from the database.